# Bug data recovery with pagePath Dimension before August 15, 2022

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to retrieve data via GA4 API using the following Metrics and Dimensions on different Accounts:
dimensions = ['date', 'eventName', 'sessionSourceMedium', 'pagePath']
metrics = ['totalRevenue', 'eventCount']
The problem is that it only returns data to me from August 15, 2022 onward, before that it doesn't show me anything.

if I remove the dimension "pagePath" the API call returns me the data prior to August 15, 2022.
However, I need the page where the various events are triggered.

Does this happen to you as well? Know how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Define page_location as custom dimension and then it will be  sent to GA4 automatically.

Comment: page_location gives you the whole URL.

Comment: If I use the following metrics and dimensions:
dimensions = ['date', 'eventName', 'sessionSourceMedium', 'pageLocation']
metrics = ['totalRevenue', 'eventCount']
response tells me, "The size and metrics of the request are incompatible.".

Comment: Surprised that pagelocation gives you that error where pagepath doesn't, but I only use LookerStudio for reporting so don't have the knowledge, anyone able to help?